# How to identify a spark operation in the console?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have a Spark job that I'm running on EMR that does some computation on different DataFrames inside a loop.

Is there any way to tag the DataFrames or add some marker in the stack frame so I can tell which operation is which when using the web console to inspect the job executions?